# youtube api - prevent title overlay on pause

Tags: youtube-api, overlay, title

Hello I'm writing advanced html5 multimedia player also with You-Tube support using YT API. and there is trobule because on my page player uses really small video area (it shows visualization in case of music / video in case of video, so appearing title on lower resolution screens (as page is dynamically sized depending on screen metrics) covers about 1/4 of video and it looks just a bit cheap. Is there any way to turn it off? eg. controls can be disabled by YT object constructor arguments, is there something simillar for this appearing top overlay? I haven't found anything about it on google page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the parameter `showinfo=0`

Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/pefow5Kp_W4?autoplay=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```